# C quick sort of a struct causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, qsort

The program is reading line by line from a file and storing info in a struct. Everything works except for sorting the array of structs. For example, at the end when I'm printing the struct(code included at the end), it works completely fine.

The problem (segmentation fault) occurs when I call the qsort.

Also, printing students[0].lastName works fine, but printing students[1].lastName returns a (null), that too is confusing.

I've looked everywhere and my code seems very similar to what has been posted as correct solutions to sorting structs, so I'm very confused.

**Defining struct in header of main:**

```
// DEFINE STRUCT
typedef struct _StudentInformation  {
    int term;
    int studentId;
    char *lastName;
    char *firstName;
    char *subject;
    int catalogNumber;
    char *section;
} StudentInformation;
```

**Allocating the struct in main method (STUDENT_DATA=50):**

```
// ALLOCATE AN ARRAY OF STUDENTS (STRUCT)
    StudentInformation *students;
    if ((students = malloc(STUDENT_DATA*sizeof(StudentInformation)))==NULL) {
        scanf("Error can't allocate enough students!\n");
        exit(1);
}
```

**The problem: Calling quicksort (the reason for the 8 is because there are 8 entries THAT WORK and are LOADED, even less than 8 doesn't work).:**

```
qsort(students, 8, sizeof(StudentInformation), comparator);
```

**Comparator for quicksort:**

```
int comparator (const void * a, const void * b) {
    StudentInformation *s1 = (StudentInformation*)a;
    StudentInformation *s2 = (StudentInformation*)b;

    return strcmp(s1->lastName, s2->lastName);
}
```

**The reason I know data is loaded fine is because printing works completely fine:**

```
void printInformation (StudentInformation *students) {
    // PRINT EVERYTHING
        while(students->firstName!=NULL) {
            printf("%-s, %s %15d %4d %4s%d %7s\n",
                    students->lastName,students->firstName,students->term,
                    students->studentId, students->subject,students->catalogNumber,
                    students->section);

            // Increment
            students=students+sizeof(StudentInformation);
        }
}
```

**What it prints (i only included 2 out of the 8 that were printed, no NULLS printed):**

```
Castille, Michael Jr            1201 103993269  CSE230     R03
Boatswain, Michael R.            1201 105515018  CSE230     R01
```

Thank you!

Comment: Anecdotal, but Bjarnes talk at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style  provides a lot of insight to your troubles.

Comment: `scanf("Error can't allocate enough students!\n");` it's `printf` not `scanf` you want to use

Comment: How do you allocate `lastName`?

Comment: The program should either fail on the line `students=students+sizeof(StudentInformation);` or skip most of the students.  Since `students` is a pointer to a `StudentInformation` structure, it should be incremented with `students++;`.  C is smart enough to know you mean "plus one _structure_."

Comment: printInformation - while(students->firstName!=NULL) i hope you put a null entry at the end of your students list ( and didnt include it in the sort )

Comment: @AdamLiss The printing function works completely fine. Only time the program fails is during the quick sort.

Comment: @AdamLiss the lack of "students++" was the problem, but my part of program didn't fail with students=students+sizeof(StudentInformation). Only the quicksort started failing though. Still not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided STUDENT_DATA >= 8, there's only one possible explanation, which is that one or more of your `lastName` fields was never initialized and contains NULL or garbage. If your loop initializing these fields contained the same error as your loop printing it out (using `students=students+sizeof(StudentInformation)` instead of `students++`), that would be why.

Comment: The printing works completely fine and there is no NULL printed. I will try students++ though

Comment: Thank you, I changed my data loading and printing with 'students++'! As some mentioned I should have used 'students++'. Can someone explain why that is what caused the problem? I thought 'students=students+sizeof(StudentInformation)' does the same thing.

Comment: @anon: When you increment a pointer to type `type` in C, its value increases by `sizeof(type)`.  So incrementing `students`, which is a pointer to `StudentInformation`, is the same as adding `sizeof(StudentInformation)` to a pointer of type `char *`.  Adding `sizeof(StudentInformation)` to `student` will increase it by `sizeof(StudentInformation) * sizeof(StudentInformation)` each time, making it eventually run past the memory you've allocated to it and leading to the "ricochet error" I described in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The line:

```
if ((students = malloc(STUDENT_DATA*sizeof(StudentInformation)))==NULL)
```

allocates memory for the structure itself, but not for the strings that are referenced by pointers:

```
char *lastName;
char *firstName;
char *subject;
char *section;
```

Each of those occupies enough memory for a pointer.  You'll need to allocate memory for the strings separately:

```
if ((lastName = malloc((LAST_NAME_LEN + 1) * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
  // Error
}
if ((firstName = ...
```

Writing to memory that you don't own is always a good way to get an unexpected lesson in debugging ricochet-errors:  you'll probably get a segfault or memory corruption eventually, but it may be in an area of code that appears to be totally unrelated to the actual source of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, but I have allocated everything hence I said that the print function works fine (I assume that is the only reason it would work). All the strings are allocated like this: "char *firstName = malloc(16);" in another method. Then that firstName, is pointed to the correct position in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

You said `Calling quicksort (the reason for the 8 is because there are 8 entries`.

This is incorrect. you should pass the number of elements in the array (`STUDENT_DATA` in your case).

Comment: Granted it's not best programming practice, but as long as 8 <= STUDENT_DATA, it shouldn't cause qsort() to segfault.

Comment: Yea I agree, but reason I put the 8 is for testing - to guarantee that I am not calling anything NULL.